# Showing that Conat Coalgebra is Terminal

Tags: agda, homotopy-type-theory, cubical-type-theory

I have a definition of Conats in Agda (actually it is the one in the [cubical library](https://github.com/agda/cubical/tree/master/Cubical/Codata/Conat)). I am trying to show that the associated F-coalgebra is (Homotopy-)terminal.

I have managed to prove the existence of a F-Coalgebra Homomorphsim into the Conat coalgebra, but I am struggling with the uniqueness aspect it.

For concreteness the functor `F` is:

```
F : Set → Set
F X = Unit ⊎ X
```

Conat/Base.agda

```
{-# OPTIONS --cubical --safe --guardedness #-}
module Cubical.Codata.Conat.Base where

open import Cubical.Data.Unit
open import Cubical.Data.Sum

open import Cubical.Core.Everything

record Conat : Set
Conat′ = Unit ⊎ Conat
record Conat where
  coinductive
  constructor conat′
  field force : Conat′
open Conat public

pattern zero  = inl tt
pattern suc n = inr n

conat : Conat′ → Conat
force (conat a) = a

succ : Conat → Conat
force (succ a) = suc a

succ′ : Conat′ → Conat′
succ′ n = suc λ where .force → n

pred′ : Conat′ → Conat′
pred′  zero   = zero
pred′ (suc x) = force x

pred′′ : Conat′ → Conat
force (pred′′ zero) = zero
pred′′ (suc x) = x

pred : Conat → Conat
force (pred x) = pred′ (force x)
```

Conat/Properties.agda  (modified to remove irrelevent stuff. This is where my code is)

```
{-# OPTIONS --cubical --safe --guardedness #-}
module Cubical.Codata.Conat.Properties where

open import Cubical.Data.Unit
open import Cubical.Data.Sum
open import Cubical.Data.Empty
import Cubical.Data.DecreasingBinarySequence
import Cubical.Data.Nat
import Cubical.Data.Bool

open import Cubical.Core.Everything
open import Cubical.Foundations.Equiv
open import Cubical.Foundations.Path
open import Cubical.Foundations.Function

open import Cubical.Relation.Nullary
open import Cubical.Relation.Nullary.DecidableEq
open import Cubical.Codata.Conat.Base

module F-Coalgebra where

  -- definition of our functor F and Coalgebra stuff

  F : Set → Set
  F X = Unit ⊎ X

  F-map : {A B : Set} → (A → B) → (F A → F B)
  F-map f (inl tt) = inl tt
  F-map f (inr x) = inr (f x)

  F-Coalgebra : Set₁
  F-Coalgebra = Σ[ C ∈ Set ] (C → F C)

  coalgebraHomomorphism : (X Y : F-Coalgebra) → Set
  coalgebraHomomorphism (C , sc) (D , sd) = Σ[ f ∈ (C → D) ] F-map f ∘ sc ≡ sd ∘ f

  isTerminalCoalgebra : F-Coalgebra → Set₁
  isTerminalCoalgebra X = (Y : F-Coalgebra) → (isContr (coalgebraHomomorphism Y X))

  -- operations on Conat that might be useful

  module coit {S : Set} where
    coit : (S → F S) → S → Conat
    coit′ : (S → F S) → F S →  Conat′
    coit f s .force = coit′ f (f s)

    coit′ f (inl tt) = zero
    coit′ f (inr x) = suc (coit f x)

    -- this needs a proper name
    yesy : (sc : S → F S) → F-map (coit sc) ≡ coit′ sc
    yesy sc i (inl tt) = zero
    yesy sc i (suc x) = suc (coit sc x)

    coitSpec : (sc : S → F S) → (s : S) → F-map (coit sc) (sc s) ≡ force (coit sc s)
    coitSpec sc s i = yesy sc i (sc s)   

  inF : F Conat → Conat
  inF x .force = x

  ioF : (x : Conat) → inF (force x) ≡ x
  ioF x i .force = refl {x = force x} i

  caseF : (P : Conat → Set) → ((t : F Conat) → P (inF t)) → (x : Conat) → P x
  caseF P p x = subst P (ioF x) (p (force x))

  -- The specific Conat F-Coalgebra

  ConatCoalgebra : F-Coalgebra
  ConatCoalgebra = Conat , force 

  ConatCoalgebraTerminal : isTerminalCoalgebra ConatCoalgebra
  ConatCoalgebraTerminal (C , sc) = (coit.coit sc , λ i s → coit.coitSpec sc s i)
    , {!!}  -- notice the hole here, this is where I'm having trouble 
            -- proving the type of morphsisms is contractible
```

The specific spot I am having trouble is marked with a hole at the end of the second file. The definition of `isContr` is

```
isContr : Set ℓ → Set ℓ
isContr A = Σ[ x ∈ A ] (∀ y → x ≡ y)
```

Because I am using the cubical mode, equality (actually paths) can be shown to coincide with bisimulation. I think this this somehow gives me coinduction, but I don't know how.

There is also available a proof that `Conat` is a hSet, that may or may not be useful for the proof.